# Scrapy TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and space in identation

Tags: python-3.x, web, scrapy, web-crawler

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
             'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
             'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Requests(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

when i execute this file with "scrapy crawl quotes", i got error in line 7 which marks my "[" and says: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in identation
but i wonder why, because i assume that i correctly "copied" the code from a video, and i tested several identations.
Currently im working on 18.04 ubuntu lts server

Comment: Somewhere in the code you've copied you're mixing tabs and spaces. PEP8 suggests that you should be doing 4 spaces and not tabs. In Python 3, this is enforced hence the TabError. My suggestion would be to start a fresh, typing it out line by line instead of copying it.

Comment: i didnt copie at all, i wrote line for line, idk how the error were created.

Comment: Regardless of how you created that code, the fact remains that the issue is your code uses a combination of tabs and spaces for indentation. You need to fix that. Most Python IDEs and advanced text editors will have an option to make spaces and tabs visible, so that you can find the root of the problem.